# How to access a JSON static file imported with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

I have this JSON static file in my project structure:

`someFile.json`

The JSON is an stringified version of an array of objects: `[{...},{...},etc]`

I'm importing it with Webpack (v 4.41.2) as:

`import '../someFile.json';`  <----- This is in my **App.js** file

But now I want to access it inside my App so I can parse it back into array and use it. How can I do it?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
import myJSONfrom '../someFile.json';
const parsedJson = JSON.parse(myJSON);

function App() {
  // USE parsedJSON
}
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

JSON File content:

```
[{"code":"STOCK","date":"2016-05-19T00:00:00.000Z","open":1240,"max":12430,"min":1240,"avg":12140,"close":12140,"numTrades":12,"amountTraded":120,"volume":121400,"quoteFactor":100},...OTHER OBJECTS....]
```

**Note:** This is a React app.

Comment: It should already be parsed when you import it. Just treat as regular JSON without needing to parse.

Comment: Thanks! You are right! Just found out about that!

Answer (score 1):

Just found out what was wrong.

```
import myJSON from '../someFile.json';     // THIS DOES WORK
// const parsedJson = JSON.parse(myJSON);  // DON'T DO THIS. IT'S ALREADY PARSED

function App() {
  // USE parsedJSON
}
```

So basically you can do:

```
import parsedJSON from '../someFile.json';     // THIS DOES WORK

function App() {
  // USE parsedJSON
}
```